# python speech recognition library / pyaudio: refresh list of mics

Tags: python, pyaudio

hi this is my first post so i will try my best to explain what i need.

My problem is that i'm using a specific mic that might disconnect at any time if so i need it to connect to my pc's mic. here is the code

```
    mic = None
    for i in sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names():
        print(i)

    for index, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
        print("Microphone with name \"{1}\" found for `Microphone(device_index={0})`".format(index, name))
        if str(name) == "Microphone (Blue Snowball)":
            print("\n\n\n\n\n")
            mic = sr.Microphone(sample_rate = 18000, device_index= index)
            print("using Microphone with name \"{1}\" found for `Microphone(device_index={0})`".format(index, name))
            print(mic)

    if mic == None:
        for index, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
            print("Microphone with name \"{1}\" found for `Microphone(device_index={0})`".format(index, name))
            if str(name) == "Microphone (Realtek High Defini":
                print("\n\n\n\n\n")
                mic = sr.Microphone(sample_rate = 18000, device_index= index)
                print("using Microphone with name \"{1}\" found for `Microphone(device_index={0})`".format(index, name))
                print(mic)
    print(mic)
```

the code above is ran 1 every 5 seconds or so

now the problem is when i disconnect the mic it still says it there

it seems like the `sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()`get the all the audio devices when the program starts then during operation when it is called again it does not update that list it just retrieves this list that was made at the start.

now i need a way to either update this list or see which mics are operational. i know pyaudio does see this mic is missing cause the device indexes changes but it does not update the list

thanks from sir snibbles

p.s i have research this for 4 hours and i don't have any experience with pyaudio